# Simplifying a set (Venn Diagram)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am practicing for a math exam about Venn Diagrams. How would you simplify this set? Thanks
$$(A \cap B) \cup (B' \cap A) $$

Comment: Verify that it is equal to $A$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The maroon area is $A\cap B$, i.e. both $A$ and $B$.

The yellow area is $B’ \cap A$, i.e. $A$ but *not* $B$.

Their union is $A$, as from the picture.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: by distributivity (and commutativity):
$$(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')=A\cap(B\cup B')$$